Creating rmd with knit_child
my goal is to use the command knit_child in a rmd so that it will appeal another rmd for different
tree species for a study.
Here is the code of my rmd with knit_child:
    ---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document: 
date: "2024-07-15"
---


```{r setup,include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

setwd("C:/DossierTravailEcoaf/AnalyseHauteurRayonAd/RapportGlobal/")
source("trees_v6_clembis.R") ```

```{r,results='asis'}
  lspecies <-read.csv2("ListeEspècesClem.txt",header=FALSE)
  lspecies<-lspecies[,1]
  res <- lapply(lspecies, function(x) {
  knitr::knit_child(
    'studySpecie.Rmd', envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE
  )
})
cat(unlist(res), sep = '\n') ```


in the file studySpecie.rmd i make some plots and statistic tests,
the problem is that when i have two or more species in my list lspecies
i get the following error message :
*
processing file: testboucleRmd.Rmd
output file: testboucleRmd.knit.md
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testboucleRmd.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output testboucleRmd.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\adelaneau\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.4\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\adelaneau\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.4\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template "C:\Users\adelaneau\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.4\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\ADELAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEXTyOq\rmarkdown-str17f0348b4349.html"
YAML parse exception at line 6, column 11:
mapping values are not allowed in this context
Erreur : pandoc document conversion failed with error 64
Exécution arrêtée
*
whereas if i have only one elment in the list, i have no error and my html file is good
I tried to find solutions on the net, but wasn't successful up to now.
Any help would be appereciated

I solved this problem, it was due to the fact i didn't write the "---" at the end of the file studySpecie.rmd's head :
---                                                                                                                               title: "Compilation des études hauteur/circonférence et rayon houppier/hauteur houppier"
author: "me"
date: "r Sys.Date()"
output:
word_document: default
